# JPA/Hibernate: Allow Integer to be null or in a set range of numbers?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I want to have an Integer field `field` in a table which should be allowed to take one of the following values:

```
null
0
1
2
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using JPA or Hibernate annotations? I've tried `@Min @Max` and `@Range` which didn't seem to work.

To be more precise: I want an error to be thrown when an insert or update command is executed which sets `field` to anything different then null, 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: `@Min`, `@Max` and `@Range` are not JPA or Hibernate annotations. They are Bean Validation API annotations. Suggest you look there for ideas http://beanvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Counter {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Null
    @Min(0)
    @Max(2)
    private int count;

    ..
    ..
}
```

For validation you need to validate like this

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
counter.setName("msg");
counter.setCount(3);

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Counter>> constraints = validator
    .validate(counter);
for (ConstraintViolation<Counter> constraint : constraints) {
    System.out.println(constraint.getPropertyPath() + "  "
    + constraint.getMessage());
```

I think this should work in your case. But its not Jpa/Hibernate validation, its bean validation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think I wasn't specific enough in my question, sorry. What I want to to have is some kind of equivalent of a column constraint, so that insert/update command on sql level would fail. If it's of any difference, the used database is oracle.

Comment: This one is Application Level validation that you can do, but if you want db 
level validation for oracle then use CHECK constraint. For more info check this https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php .